# Removing console log statements in release version [Nativescript]

Tags: nativescript

In the release version of the app, are the `console` log statements included?

If so - is there a way to remove it - preferably using hooks.

I know I can use `trace` logging - but I believe that still doesn't get rid of expressions being calculated inside the statement.

`console.log( "text=" + long_call() );`

I'd like to remove the entire statement - including the expressions inside the statement.

Comment: They are not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove console statements using Webpack. In `webpack.config.js`, under `terserOptions` -> `compress`, set `drop_console` to `true` on release build.

```
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                ...
                terserOptions: {
                    ...
                    compress: {
                        // You may also set this value based on environment variables / CLI params
                        drop_console: true,
                        ...
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
```

Comment: It depends on whether or not you are passing `--env.uglify` which you would generally do only on release build.